# AssertionError using dissolve function from GeoPandas v0.11

Tags: python, jupyter, geopandas, assertion

I am having an issue lately with the latest version of geopandas (0.11) that was not present when I run this code some months ago (around April 2022). I am wondering if this is due to a new update on this package.

I have a GeoDataframe called `shapefile_HD` with the following data: heat demand ("HD"), geometry (squares of 1ha each), centroid coordinates (x,y), land area (1ha), gross floor area, and cluster number. I used to use the function "dissolve" to aggregate the cells into polygons with the same cluster number:

[image: shapefile_HD]

```py
dissolve = shapefile_HD.dissolve(by='cluster', as_index=False)
```

In the past, this easily worked, but now I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-59672e9e6d3a> in <module>
----> 1 dissolve = shapefile_HD.dissolve(by='cluster', as_index=False)
      2 dissolve
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in dissolve(self, by, aggfunc, as_index, level, sort, observed, dropna)
   1702 
   1703         # Process non-spatial component
-> 1704         data = self.drop(labels=self.geometry.name, axis=1)
   1705         aggregated_data = data.groupby(**groupby_kwargs).agg(aggfunc)
   1706         aggregated_data.columns = aggregated_data.columns.to_flat_index()
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3988                 weight  1.0     0.8
   3989         """
-> 3990         return super().drop(
   3991             labels=labels,
   3992             axis=axis,
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3934         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3935             if labels is not None:
-> 3936                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3937 
   3938         if inplace:
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3969             else:
   3970                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
-> 3971             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3972 
   3973         # Case for non-unique axis
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    225         @wraps(func)
    226         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 227             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    228 
    229         kind = inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3854         kwargs.pop("axis", None)
   3855         kwargs.pop("labels", None)
-> 3856         return self._ensure_type(super().reindex(**kwargs))
   3857 
   3858     def drop(
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/data-visualization-course/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _ensure_type(self, obj)
     91         Used by type checkers.
     92         """
---> 93         assert isinstance(obj, type(self)), type(obj)
     94         return obj
     95 
AssertionError: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I tried to install a previous version of geopandas (v10, v9, and v8) and I got this error:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
  - defaults/noarch::sphinx==2.4.0=py_0
  - anaconda/osx-64::_anaconda_depends==2020.02=py38_0
  - anaconda/osx-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.8.4=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py38_0
  - defaults/osx-64::matplotlib==3.1.3=py38_0
  - defaults/osx-64::scikit-image==0.16.2=py38h6c726b0_0
  - defaults/osx-64::spyder==4.0.1=py38_0
  - anaconda/osx-64::scikit-learn==0.22.1=py38h27c97d8_0
  - defaults/noarch::numpydoc==0.9.2=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::requests==2.22.0=py38_1
  - defaults/noarch::seaborn==0.10.0=py_0
```

Comment: The install issues could probably be resolved by installing a new environment for each one rather than trying to patch your existing env with a downgraded version of one package. As for the core issue, that looks like a real problem to me, though I’d be surprised if the newest version of geopandas can’t do dissolves or groupby operations and no one has raised an issue about it. At least, I didn’t see one. If you can create a full [mre] that has this behavior in a clean install env I’m sure the geopandas team would love to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

Have simulated an equivalent *GeoDataFrame*. This does not fail on my env using **geopandas** v0.11

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry

gdfp = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities")).loc[lambda d: d["name"].eq("London")]
crs = gdfp.estimate_utm_crs()
STEP = 100
a,b,c,d = [v+(o*10**3) for o, v in zip([-1,-1,1,1], gdfp.to_crs(crs).total_bounds)]

# create one hectre grid geometries
shapefile_HD = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
        for minx, maxx in zip(np.arange(a, c, STEP), np.arange(a, c, STEP)[1:])
        for miny, maxy in zip(np.arange(b, d, STEP), np.arange(b, d, STEP)[1:])
    ],
    crs=crs,
).to_crs(gdfp.crs)

# add noted attributes
shapefile_HD["x"] = shapefile_HD["geometry"].centroid.x
shapefile_HD["y"] = shapefile_HD["geometry"].centroid.y
shapefile_HD["landarea"] = 100**2
r = np.random.RandomState(42)
shapefile_HD["GHA"] = r.randint(7,4000, len(shapefile_HD))
shapefile_HD["cluster"] = r.randint(7,16, len(shapefile_HD))

# code
dissolve = shapefile_HD.dissolve(by='cluster', as_index=False)
```

I suggest you check your **geopandas** dependencies.

```
gpd.show_versions()
```

```
SYSTEM INFO
-----------
python     : 3.10.6 (main, Aug 30 2022, 05:11:14) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
executable : python3.10/venv/bin/python3.10
machine    : macOS-11.6.8-x86_64-i386-64bit

GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO
---------------------
GEOS       : 3.11.0
GEOS lib   : /usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.11.0/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
GDAL       : 3.4.1
GDAL data dir: python3.10/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fiona/gdal_data
PROJ       : 8.2.0
PROJ data dir: python3.10/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyproj/proj_dir/share/proj

PYTHON DEPENDENCIES
-------------------
geopandas  : 0.11.1
numpy      : 1.23.3
pandas     : 1.5.1
pyproj     : 3.3.1
shapely    : 1.8.4
fiona      : 1.8.21
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : 2.2.0
matplotlib : 3.5.3
mapclassify: 2.4.3
pygeos     : 0.13
pyogrio    : None
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : 9.0.0
rtree      : 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replies.

I solved the issue by installing a new environment.

I still had incompatibilities depending on the order in which I installed the packages. There was an issue in the versions among geopandas, fiona, and GDAL. Initially, I thought it was because of a mix of channels (default vs conda-forge). But after trying a few times with different new environments, and making sure that I was installing everything using the default channel through the terminal, I found a different way of installing them.

The only thing that worked was to install the packages in this order (in the Jupyter notebook that I was working on):

```
!pip install -U pyshp
!pip install -U shapely
!pip install -U descartes
!pip install -U pygeos
!pip install -U rtree
!pip install -U geopandas
```

It would be nice if someone could explain me why this type of problem happened.

Comment: Something important to add is that this jupyter notebook was abandoned for about a year. A compatibility issue occurred when I upgraded the packages from the previous list. I never had to install a new environment since I started my project 1.5 years ago. Maybe I was lucky! I didn't know that these issues are pretty normal.